# What is the exact command to install yum through brew?

Tags: homebrew, yum

I tried installing yum through brew install command. but it is not working with the message below. What is the problem? I can not find any good materials.

```
$ brew install "yum"
Error: No available formula with the name "yum" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: It is described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80711/how-to-install-apt-get-or-yum-on-mac-os-x).Please check if its helpful

Comment: @CrshnaPariyar I tried with that.. But after I install brew, I run the command "brew install yum". LIke I said, I failed like the above. Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`yum` is a package manager for Red Hat Linux. It will not work on macOS. `brew` is a package manager for macOS

So instead of trying to install `yum` to install another piece of software, you might want to try to install this software using `brew` directly. But beware: the package names might not be the same. Use `brew search` to search for packages in brew, or maybe, even better, try and find specific instructions for macOS for the software you're trying to install.